# Get the result for the last Task<> ( continuation)?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I have this sample code :

```
Task<int> t1= new Task<int>(()=>1);
t1.ContinueWith(r=>1+r.Result).ContinueWith(r=>1+r.Result);
t1.Start();

Console.Write(t1.Result); //1
```

It obviously return the `Result` from the `t1` task. ( which is 1)

But how can I get the `Result` from the **last** continued task ( it should be `3` {1+1+1})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405.aspx) itself returns a task -  `Task<int>` in this case. You can do anything (more or less - you can't manually `Start` a continuation, for example) you wish with this task that you could have done with the 'original' task, including waiting for its completion and inspecting its result.

```
var t1 = new Task<int>( () => 1);
var t2 = t1.ContinueWith(r => 1 + r.Result)
           .ContinueWith(r => 1 + r.Result);

t1.Start();

Console.Write(t1.Result); //1
Console.Write(t2.Result); //3
```

Comment: Why does it matter where I put write the continueWith ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you clarify? The TPL is 'consistent' in this case in the sense that a continuation of a task is also a task.

Comment: I know that continuewith returns a Task. Q: I think it's pretty simple : t1 referes to the first task only. later this task is being added with another tasks but I cant access them from outside. but in your answer , t2 does refer to the last continued task , so you CAN get the value. is that correct ?

Comment: You want to ask a task for all its continuations and then recursively *their* continuations and so on, until you find the 'last` continuation?

Comment: No. I think you've answered my question. I think it's all a references issue. myne reference only to the original task while yours reference  to the last continued task. that's all.  (please confirm). PS is there any property on a Task which tells me its continuation tasks ? Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right that `t2` references the last continuation. To answer your second question, there is no public property on a Task to get its continuations (this wouldn't really be in the spirit of the TPL, IMO), but you could use some reflection hackery to do so, theoretically. Wouldn't recommend it, though.